# words selection

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

"highlight" the searched desired word. What i'm trying to achieve: clicking on the next or previous button i want to select only the underlined single word and navigate in sequence back and forth  on the words founded. So, how can i do, having five words founded,to select only the third word after the first two? ex. :

[image]

i've tried this expression : `^(?:\w+ ){2}\K\w+` but making some test i cannot able to find my desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex matches only the 3rd hello: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GALozt/1)

```
(?<=(?:Hello.*){2})(?<!(?:Hello.*){3})Hello
```

This is using a positive lookbehind to test if at least 2 `"Hello"`s have been passed, and a negative lookbehind to test if 3 or more have not been passed. If at least 2 have been passed and not 3 or more then only 2 `"Hello"`s have passed.